# Excel 2010 connection with SSAS 2008

Tags: excel, attributes, ssas, dimension, olap-cube

I have a pivot table on excel which uses SSAS Cube. I have  selected some report filter as well as some row labels.Later I changed the attribute relationships in the dimension.
I didn't change the names of the attributes of the dimension.

But now when I refresh my excel, all the report filters disappear.
As this excel is on the client site it would create a problem as they do not want to select the filters again.
The dimension still can be seen in the pivot table and has to be selected again.

Can anyone suggest what can be done?

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean?